# "Error during wrapup: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector" when trying to write a function

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to replicate this piece of code as a function.

It removes all the NA observations in variable Q19 and all associated observations in variable StartDate.

`timeperceptions <- timeperceptions[!(timeperceptions$StartDate >= '09/17/15' & is.na(timeperceptions$Q19)) & !(timeperceptions$StartDate <= '03/16/16' & is.na(timeperceptions$Q19)) ,]`

My function looks like this

```
naremover <- function(df, col1, col2, time1, time2) {
  df[!(df$col1 >= 'time1' & is.na(df$col2)) & !(df$col1 <= 'time2' & is.na(df$col2)), ]

  }
testing2 <- naremover(timeperceptions, StartDate, Q19, 09/17/15, 03/16/16)
```

It takes the data frame, the 2 relative columns, and the time series dates in which to constrict the relative observations to.
However, when I call it, I am left with this error

```
Error during wrapup: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 740 but subscript `&...` has size 0.
```

What can I do to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When writing a function don't use `$` to refer to a particular column, use `[[`

```
naremover <- function(df, col1, col2, time1, time2) {
  df[!(df[[col1]] >= time1 & is.na(df[[col2]])) & 
     !(df[[col1]] <= time2 & is.na(df[[col2]])), ]
}
```

- When dealing with dates always ensure that your data is of class Date and not character/factor.
- Pass column names as character in the function.
- Pass `time1` and `time2` of class Date as well.

```
timeperceptions$StartDate <- as.Date(timeperceptions$StartDate, "%m/%d/%y")
timeperceptions$Q19 <- as.Date(timeperceptions$Q19, "%m/%d/%y")

testing2 <- naremover(timeperceptions, "StartDate", "Q19", 
                      as.Date('2015-09-17'), as.Date('2016-03-16'))
```